# Calculated column based on another calculated field BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sas, calculated-columns

Hello I'm trying to use an already calculated value in a select to calculate another value, for example:

```sql
SELECT 1+1 AS two, ***two* + 2** AS four FROM table
```

is this possible in BigQuery? I'm sure it's on SAS with the keyword CALCULATED as follows:

```sql
SELECT 1+1 as two, ***CALCULATED two* + 2** AS four FROM table
```

Thank you,

Comment: Why not just replicate the expression used to make TWO as part of the expression used to make FOUR?  `(1+1) +2 as four`

Comment: Well because it could be really complex expression and it will be really hard to read in the future or other dev.

Answer (score 5):

Below is example of how I personally approach such scenario (quite frequently btw)

```
SELECT two, two + 2 AS four 
FROM table, UNNEST([STRUCT(1+1 as two)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an alias in same select. An option could be use a subselect:

```
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT 1+1 AS two FROM table
)
SELECT two + 2 AS four FROM my_table
```